# What's the command to "reset" a bokeh plot?

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, bokeh

I have a bokeh figure that has a reset button in the toolbar. Basically, I want to "reset" the figure when I update the data that I'm plotting in the figure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** A PR has been submitted for this feature. After Bokeh `0.12.16` is released, the following will work:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(tools="reset,pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select")
p.circle(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))

b = Button()
b.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
    p.reset.emit()
"""))

show(column(p, b))
```

---

As of Bokeh `0.12.1` there is no built in function to do this. It would possible to make a [custom extension](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) that does this. However, that would take a little work and experimentation and dialogue. If you'd like to pursue that option, I'd encourage you to come to the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) which is better suited to iterative collaboration and discussion than SO. Alternatively, please feel free to open a feature request on the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I took your suggestion to make a feature request: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5071

Answer (score 2):

Example with a radiogroup callback, that's the best way I found to reset while changing plots, just get the range of the data and set it to the range:

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, RadioGroup
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

x0 = range(10)
x1 = range(100)
y0 = [i for i in x0]
y1 = [i*2 for i in x1][::-1]


fig=Figure()

source1=ColumnDataSource(data={"x":[],"y":[]})
source2=ColumnDataSource(data={"x0":x0,"x1":x1,"y0":y0,"y1":y1})

p = fig.line(x='x',y='y',source=source1)

callback=CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1,s2=source2,px=fig.x_range,py=fig.y_range),  code="""
    var d1 = s1.get("data");
    var d2 = s2.get("data");
    var val = cb_obj.active;

    d1["y"] = [];
    var y = d2["y"+val];
    var x = d2["x"+val];

    var min = Math.min( ...y );
    var max = Math.max( ...y );

    py.set("start",min);
    py.set("end",max);

    var min = Math.min( ...x );
    var max = Math.max( ...x );

    px.set("start",min);
    px.set("end",max);

    for(i=0;i<=y.length;i++){
        d1["y"].push(d2["y"+val][i]);
        d1["x"].push(d2["x"+val][i]);
    }

    s1.trigger("change");
    """)

radiogroup=RadioGroup(labels=['First plot','Second plot'],active=0,callback=callback)

grid = gridplot([[fig,radiogroup]])

outfile=open('TEST.html','w')
outfile.write(file_html(grid,CDN,'Reset'))
outfile.close()
```

The Bokeh website is seriously lacking in examples for different ways to set callbacks for the different widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to make it work with Bokeh 2.2.1, but this JS `p.reset.emit()` does not seem to work.

What worked for me was to manually set the Figure `renderers` attribute to an empty list inside a callback function, called via `on_click()`. This only works with a Bokeh server running, though:

```sh
$ bokeh serve --show example.py
```

**example.py**:

```py
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

p = figure(tools="reset,pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select")
p.circle(list(range(10)), list(range(10)))

def clear_plot(attr):
    p.renderers = []

b = Button(label="Clear plot")
b.on_click(clear_plot)

curdoc().add_root(column(p, b))
```